# Issue with ObservableCollection itemsource updating and losing focus of control

Tags: c#, wpf

I've tried searching for hours and trouble shooting different messy "workarounds" but came to absolutely nothing. I have a DataGrid with the itemsource binded to a ObservableCollection and SelectedItem binded to property in viewmodel. My issue is everytime my ObservableCollection changes it of course sends propertychanged event to the view but for some reason the focus is completely removed from datagrid. So this creates a problem of losing the selected item AND not being focused. Ive started to attempt to set focus back on datagrid when it loses focus if a certain property in viewmodel is true. I tried doing this in a style trigger with focus manager and code behind but it doesnt seem to work. My project is pretty large atm so Ive created a git repo with the smallest example of this behaviour, it is linked at the bottom.

Here is the style I tried to set focus back on datagrid but it didnt seem to do anything

```
<Style x:Key="FocusableDataGrid" TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Populated}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I also tried changing focus from code behind but I couldn't get it to work.

A big issue for me here is the fact that I update the list after CellEditEnding is triggered which means after editing a combobox I simply lose SelectedItem and Focus, after editing a textbox if I press enter I lose selected item but not focus (SelectedItem goes from null to first item) but if I press tab or esc or anything else I lose both SelectedItem and focus. This behaviour is super annoying and hopefully there is a way around it. To reiterate once again, these behaviours can be seen in action in the linked git repo.

https://github.com/LucasAWeber/WPF-DataGrid-Focus-Issue

Comment: Your problem is too general. But you provided too few details to understand it. It will be better if you make a minimal example that reproduces the problem. Upload it to GitHub. And provide us with a link to this repository.

Comment: @EldHasp ah, good call I'll do that now

Comment: @EldHasp Added repo that reproduces this behaviour

Comment: I'm not sure what our exact problem is or if you simply confuse the behavior of the ItemsControl or if I confuse your question. When you clear the source collection, you also remove the currently selected item. This should be obvious. Adding new items does not automatically select anything. The items may contain same *values* but they are not the same *instances*. If you want to define object equality by value, you must override the object.Equals member. to redefine equality. Otherwise, you must programmatically select the desired item after you have cleared the collectio..

Comment: What is the purpose of your code? You reset the current items source when you edit a cell??? That's weird. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @BionicCode There is more to my actual project then just clearing, I first save all the entries into a different property and then redraw collection with anything that has changed in the code. I understand the selected item is cleared and I tried working around that but the main issue right now is the fact that the moment OnPropertyChanged is triggered the datagrid loses all focus and im not sure how to get around that

Comment: OnPropertyChanged is only raised on property changes. This means that you have replaced the collection instance. This means the ItemsControl will completely initialize itself again and even if the new collection instance contains the exact same items, the property change will force the ItemsControl to rebuild. Which will cause lost of focus and selected item index.

Comment: @BionicCode lol ye ty I was banging my head on the wall for a bit but I was just being stupid you made me realize something... I thought OnPropertyChanged was the culprit but I actually missed the fact in my original project when testing (literally changing nothing and sending the OnPropertyChanged) the whole datagrid would refresh and lose focus, what I didnt realize was it was because I had IsAsync = True which apparently causes this refresh which I wasnt aware about so after removing that I can do what I want to do. ty

Comment: OnPropertyChanged for the collection object? If you are reassigning the property to which ItemsSource is bound, of course you will lose all context in the control because it's a new collection as far as the control is concerned. To preserve context, you only want to update items in the existing collection without altering/reassigning the property to which ItemsSource is bound. Note that ObservableCollection exposes the CollectionChanged event which is automatically handled by ItemsControl and its derivates (including DataGrid).

Comment: @struggling-to-work I can't access your repository.
Most likely you accidentally set a “private repository” in its settings.

Comment: *"I wasn't aware about so after removing that I can do what I want to do"* - No that's not the case. If you disable deferred binding or asynchronous binding, the ItemsControl uses an equality check to test if the value has actually changed. If it hasn't, the event is ignored. If the equality test fails, the binding engine has to create and register a new collection view, and the ItemsControl has to measure and arrange its complete layout again, which leads to invalidation of the control's current visual state (focus, selected items, highlighting  etc.).

Comment: Changing the collection instance is *always* very expensive and therefore very inefficient and should be avoided, no matter if the binding is asynchronous or synchronous.

Comment: *"I was banging my head on the wall for a bit"* - Always wear a helmet at your desk. It also protects you against pulling out your valuable and beautiful hair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The INotifyCollectinCnahged event is handled synchronously in WPF. Therefore, clearing a collection also causes the selection of elements in this collection to be reset.
Here is an example of a test implementation in which new elements are not even created, but the same ones that were before the collection was cleared are added.

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        //[ObservableProperty]
        //private ObservableCollection<TestObj> test;

        public ObservableCollection<TestObj> Tests { get; } = new()
        {
            new TestObj()
            {
                Name = "Test1",
                Text = "Test1",
            },
            new TestObj()
            {
                Name = "Test2",
                Text = "Test2",
            },
            new TestObj()
            {
                Name = "Test3",
                Text = "Test3",
            },
            new TestObj()
            {
                Name = "Test4",
                Text = "Test4",
            }
        };

        //public MainWindowViewModel()
        //{
        //    Test = new ObservableCollection<TestObj>();
        //    Populate();
        //}

        [RelayCommand]
        private void Populate()
        {
            var tests = Tests.ToArray();

            // In addition to cleaning, the selected element is also reset here.
            Tests.Clear();

            Array.ForEach(tests, t => Tests.Add(t));
            //Tests.Add(
            //new TestObj()
            //{
            //    Name = "Test1",
            //    Text = "Test1",
            //});
            //Tests.Add(new TestObj()
            //{
            //    Name = "Test2",
            //    Text = "Test2",
            //});
            //Tests.Add(new TestObj()
            //{
            //    Name = "Test3",
            //    Text = "Test3",
            //});
            //Tests.Add(new TestObj()
            //{
            //    Name = "Test4",
            //    Text = "Test4",
            //});
        }
    }
}
```

The problem of remembering and restoring the selected element can be solved this way:

```cs
namespace TestApp
{
    public record TestObj(int Id)
    {
        private string _name = string.Empty;
        private string _text = string.Empty;

        public string Name { get => _name; set => _name = value ?? string.Empty; }
        public string Text { get => _text; set => _text = value ?? string.Empty; }
    }
}
```

```cs
        [RelayCommand]
        private void Populate()
        {
            int selectedTestId = SelectedTest?.Id ?? 0;

            Tests.Clear();

            Tests.Add(
            new TestObj(1)
            {
                Name = "Test1",
                Text = "Test1",
            });
            Tests.Add(new TestObj(2)
            {
                Name = "Test2",
                Text = "Test2",
            });
            Tests.Add(new TestObj(3)
            {
                Name = "Test3",
                Text = "Test3",
            });
            Tests.Add(new TestObj(4)
            {
                Name = "Test4",
                Text = "Test4",
            });

            if (Tests.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == selectedTestId) is TestObj test) 
            {
                SelectedTest = test;
            }

        }
```

But there is still a problem with losing keyboard focus while clearing the collection. Therefore, I recommend that instead of clearing the collection when reinitializing it, replacing the elements in it.
I have a class with extension methods for collections. There is also such a method there.

```cs
using System.Collections;

namespace TestApp
{
    public static partial class CollectionHelper
    {
        public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            if (collection is ICollection coll)
            {
                lock (coll.SyncRoot)
                    PrivateAddRange(collection, source);
            }
            else
            {
                PrivateAddRange(collection, source);
            }
        }

        private static void PrivateAddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            foreach (var item in source)
                collection.Add(item);
        }

        public static void Initial<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            if (collection is ICollection coll)
            {
                lock (coll.SyncRoot)
                    PrivateInitial(collection, source);
            }
            else
            {
                PrivateInitial(collection, source);
            }
        }
        private static void PrivateInitial<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            collection.Clear();
            collection.PrivateAddRange(source);
        }

        public static void InitialByReplace<T>(this IList<T> list, IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            if (list is ICollection coll)
            {
                lock (coll.SyncRoot)
                    PrivateInitialByReplace(list, source);
            }
            else
            {
                PrivateInitialByReplace(list, source);
            }
        }
        private static void PrivateInitialByReplace<T>(this IList<T> list, IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            int index = 0;
            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                if (index < list.Count)
                    list[index] = item;
                else
                    list.Add(item);
                index++;
            }
            for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= index; i--)
            {
                list.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }

        public static bool Replace<T>(this IList<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate, T newItem)
        {
            if (list is ICollection coll)
            {
                lock (coll.SyncRoot)
                    return PrivateReplace(list, predicate, newItem);
            }
            else
            {
                return PrivateReplace(list, predicate, newItem);
            }
        }
        private static bool PrivateReplace<T>(this IList<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate, T newItem)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                if (predicate(list[i]))
                {
                    list[i] = newItem;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public static bool ReplaceOrAdd<T>(this IList<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate, T newItem)
        {
            if (list is ICollection coll)
            {
                lock (coll.SyncRoot)
                    return list.PrivateReplaceOrAdd(predicate, newItem);
            }
            else
            {
                return list.PrivateReplaceOrAdd(predicate, newItem);
            }
        }
        private static bool PrivateReplaceOrAdd<T>(this IList<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate, T newItem)
        {
            if (list.PrivateReplace(predicate, newItem))
                return true;

            list.Add(newItem);
            return false;
        }

        public static bool RemoveFirst<T>(this IList<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate)
        {
            if (list is ICollection coll)
            {
                lock (coll.SyncRoot)
                    return list.PrivateRemoveFirst(predicate);
            }
            else
            {
                return list.PrivateRemoveFirst(predicate);
            }
        }
        private static bool PrivateRemoveFirst<T>(this IList<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                if (predicate(list[i]))
                {
                    list.RemoveAt(i);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> GetEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
        {
            foreach (T item in collection)
                yield return item;
        }


        public static int RemoveAll<T>(this IList<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate)
        {
            if (list is ICollection coll)
            {
                lock (coll.SyncRoot)
                    return list.PrivateRemoveAll(predicate);
            }
            else
            {
                return list.PrivateRemoveAll(predicate);
            }
        }
        private static int PrivateRemoveAll<T>(this IList<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (predicate(list[i]))
                {
                    list.RemoveAt(i);
                    count++;
                }
            }

            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private TestObj? selectedTest;

        public ObservableCollection<TestObj> Tests { get; } = new();

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Populate();
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private void Populate()
        {
            int selectedTestId = SelectedTest?.Id ?? 0;

            // Tests.Clear();

            Tests.InitialByReplace(new TestObj[]
            {
                new(1)
                {
                    Name = "Test1",
                    Text = "Test1",
                },
                new(2)
                {
                    Name = "Test2",
                    Text = "Test2",
                },
                new(3)
                {
                    Name = "Test3",
                    Text = "Test3",
                },
                new(4)
                {
                    Name = "Test4",
                    Text = "Test4",
                }
            });

            if (Tests.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == selectedTestId) is TestObj test) 
            {
                SelectedTest = test;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Tests}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTest}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PopulateCommand, Source={StaticResource vm}}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
```

A small additional benefit with this implementation will be a possible reduction in the load on the GUI.

I would like to point out that I completely agree with @BionicCode. Replacing the entire collection when changing one of the properties of one of the elements of this collection is nonsense. But you wrote that this is an abbreviated piece of code that does not fully reveal your task. Therefore, in this part I rely on your wisdom in using something like this.

Example with updating and replacing only one entity in the collection:

```cs
    public class DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgsConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        private DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgsConverter() { }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs args = (DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs)value;
            return args.Row.DataContext;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public static DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgsConverter Instance { get; } = new DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgsConverter();
    }
```

```cs
    public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private TestObj? selectedTest;

        public ObservableCollection<TestObj> Tests { get; } = new()
        {
            new(1)
            {
                Name = "Test1",
                Text = "Test1",
            },
            new(2)
            {
                Name = "Test2",
                Text = "Test2",
            },
            new(3)
            {
                Name = "Test3",
                Text = "Test3",
            },
            new(4)
            {
                Name = "Test4",
                Text = "Test4",
            }
        };

        //public MainWindowViewModel()
        //{
        //    Populate();
        //}

        [RelayCommand]
        private void Populate(TestObj test)
        {
            if (test == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            int selectedTestId = SelectedTest?.Id ?? 0;

            // Some action for "test"
            TestObj @new = new(test.Id)
            {
                Name = test.Name + ": Save",
                Text = test.Text + ": Save"
            };


            Tests.Replace(item => item.Id==@new.Id,@new);

            if (selectedTestId == @new.Id)
            {
                SelectedTest = @new;
            }
        }
    }
```

```xml
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PopulateCommand, Source={StaticResource vm}}"
                                           EventArgsConverter="{x:Static local:DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgsConverter.Instance}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the IsAsync property set to true on the DataGrid causes the entire control to refresh when the itemscontrol sends the OnPropertyChanged signal (event without actual changes to source). I was using IsAsync in hope it would speed up load times when switching between tabs but was unaware of this behaviour...
I was so unaware of this I didn't even include it in my test repo thinking it wasn't affecting it one bit.

Comment: Important: the ItemsControl will *always* rebuild once the collection instance has changed.  The only difference ist that when the binding is defined as asynchronous binding, then the simple event will trigger this rebuild. This is because the handling of the change is deferred. When using the default synchronous binding behavior, the ItemsControl can immediately check the new value for equality. If the value hasn't changed the event is ignored.

Comment: It is always recommended to clear a collection instead of replacing it. This avoids the creation of new collection views by the binding engine and the rendering overhead of the layout rebuild etc. It's very expensive to replace the collection instance.

Answer (score 0):

when lose focused, it means the ViewModel change

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).